# Keep program in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a little program that is designed as Win32 GUI. It doesn't open cmd by default, however, it prints some important data to stdout. I wan't to get that data, so I tried to execute it directly from cmd.

When I run the program from cmd, it instantly frees the console and I can type something again. Although, I tried to do `Program.exe | cat` (I have cygwin installed) and it worked perfectly.

Now, the only problem is, that the program can't change cursor position, text color, and so on. I know that they are changed like that:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), fg + bg * 16);
```

Is there any way I can use the command line with this program? As I said, piping output won't satisfy me untill it allows modifications. Im not aware of side programs, launchers, even asm patches would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: win (gui) programs do not normally attach a console. Maybe it's using OutputDebugString? You could try running DebugView from Sysinternals (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) and capture win32

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pause` command in a script.

```
Program.exe
pause
```

Or try running `cmd` with the `/k` argument:

```
cmd.exe /K
```

Comment: None worked. Window appears and waits till the execution ends, but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you want to grab output to a static (text) file then there is no way to 'move cursor' in that file, but you'll see the esc-sequences or just binary data instead.

Just as guess: try `Program.exe > c:\mytest.txt`

Comment: SetConsoleTextAttribute edits the internal properties of console as window, not the output. The ansii escape codes work on *nix only. Outputting to file gives totally nothing, even less than `| cat`.